# Positioning leaflet divIcon when adjusting size using css

Tags: leaflet, icon, css

I am using the `L.divIcon` when using `iconSize:null` which is causing `iconAnchor:[0,0]` to not be recognized,my code looks like this:

```
  var divIcon =L.divIcon({
    className:'current-location-icon',
    html:'<i class="fa fa-location-arrow fa-2x"></i>',
    iconAnchor:[0,0],
    iconSize:null,
    popupAnchor:[0,0]
});
```

How can I ensure that the icon is visible exactly at `[0,0]` when adjusting size using CSS?

Answer (score 3):

You could just add another standard marker to see the correct location:
http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/my565p1m/
If the location of your divIcon is ok, remove the standard marker again ;)

Comment: Thank you, this helped me adjust the iconAnchor so much more easily.